# What kind of a priori distribution for the Markov Switching models?

Tags: bayesian, prior, garch, hidden-markov-model

Why in the Markov-Switching models is chosen as prior distribution for the probability of the transaction as follows:

$$f(P) \propto \prod_{i=1}^K \left(\prod_{j=1}^K p_{i,j}\right) I \left\{0 < p_{i,j} < 1\right\}$$
where
$$P= 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{1,1} & \cdots & p_{1,1}\\
\vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
p_{K,1} & \cdots & p_{K,K}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
What kind of distribution is it and what is its meaning?

[Forecasting risk with Markov-switching GARCH models:A large-scale performance study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207018300840)

Answer (score 0):

From the paper:

The prior density for the transition matrix is obtained by assuming that the K rows are independent and follow a Dirichlet prior with all hyperparameters equal to two.